# What does not located within the filtered view of the tree mean?

Tags: perforce, p4v

I'm trying to Download a file with `Get Revision...` and `Force Operation` on Perforce. The log says that the operation was completed.

```
p4 sync -f /Folder/.yarnrc#head
    1 file updated
```

But when I switch to the Workspace tree I get the error:

```
The folder /Folder/.yarnrc is not located within the filtered view of the tree.
```

- The workspace mappings are the same I've used on three other machines and they were fine.
- Other sibling files (files inside /Folder) were downloaded correctly
- Looks like this is happening only with files that begin their name with a dot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "filtered view of the tree" is a P4V thing, not a general Perforce thing (i.e. it's not the same as the `View` in your client spec).  If you look for a little funnel icon on the taskbar that's where the filters are set for the workspace pane -- maybe something is set there that excludes this file?  Like a setting to exclude "hidden" files?

Comment: In my case, I had to make sure I had ['Workspace Root' selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5e16.png)